# Why doesn't Lucene find any documents with this code?

Tags: java, search, full-text-search, lucene

I am working on this piece of code which add a single document to a lucene (4.7) index and then try to find it by quering a term that exists in the document for sure. But indexSearcher doesn't return any document. What is wrong with my code? Thank you for your comments and feedbacks.

```
String indexDir = "/home/richard/luc_index_03";
    try {
        Directory directory = new SimpleFSDirectory(new File(
                indexDir));
        Analyzer analyzer = new SimpleAnalyzer(
                Version.LUCENE_47);
        IndexWriterConfig conf = new IndexWriterConfig(
                Version.LUCENE_47, analyzer);
        conf.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
        conf.setRAMBufferSizeMB(256.0);
        IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(
                directory, conf);

        Document doc = new Document();
        String title="New York is an awesome city to live!";
        doc.add(new StringField("title", title, StringField.Store.YES));
        indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
        indexWriter.commit();
        indexWriter.close();
        directory.close();
        IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader
                .open(FSDirectory.open(new File(
                        indexDir)));
        IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(
                reader);


        String field="title";
        SimpleQueryParser qParser = new SimpleQueryParser(analyzer, field);
        String queryText="New York" ; 
        Query query = qParser.parse(queryText);
        int hitsPerPage = 100;
        TopDocs results = indexSearcher.search(query, 5 * hitsPerPage);
        System.out.println("number of results: "+results.totalHits);
        ScoreDoc[] hits = results.scoreDocs;
        int numTotalHits = results.totalHits;

        for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc:hits){
            Document docC = indexSearcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc);
            String path = docC.get("path");
            String titleC = docC.get("title");
            String ne = docC.get("ne");
            System.out.println(path+"\n"+titleC+"\n"+ne);
            System.out.println("---*****----");

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

After running I just get

```
number of results: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you use `StringField`. From the javadoc:

> A field that is indexed but not tokenized: the entire String value is indexed as a single token.

Just use `TextField` instead and you should be ok.